# RF24 communication between Leonardo and Micro not responding

Tags: communication, arduino-leonardo, nrf24l01+

I have Arduino Leonardo and Micro. I can't manage them to communicate via nRF24L01. I made a receiver and sender sketch to test it and can't see any respond. I tested the same code on two arduino nano and they work fine.

I connected the pins correctly using the ICSP pins in Leonardo and corresponding pins (not ICSP) dedicated for SPI in Micro.

Please could someone tell me what am I missing in porting sketch from nano-nano to leonardo-micro?

Here are the sketches:

PS some additional channels are left to see what I expected from working sketch.

Receiver module:

```
//NRF24
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
RF24 radio(9, 10);
byte addresses[][6] = {"1Node", "2Node", "3Node", "4Node"};

int channel = 1;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(1);
  radio.setRetries(15, 15);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(2, addresses[1]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(3, addresses[2]);
  radio.openReadingPipe(4, addresses[3]);
  radio.startListening();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while (radio.available()) { 
    char theMessage[13];
     radio.read(&theMessage, 13);
     Serial.println(theMessage);
     if(theMessage == "testingsend"){
       //this is removed in nano
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      delay(50);
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
     }
  }
}
```

And the sender:

```
//NRF24
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
RF24 radio(9, 10);
byte addresses[][6] = {"1Node", "2Node", "3Node", "4Node"};

int channel = 1;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  radio.begin();
  radio.setAutoAck(1);
  radio.setRetries(15, 15);
  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[channel]);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  char theMessage[13] = "testingsend";
  radio.write(theMessage, sizeof(theMessage));
  memset(theMessage,0,sizeof(theMessage));
  delay(300);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the ICSP header on the Micro? Since it's unlikely that your code is the problem, try other combinations to pin-point the issue like, Leonardo-Nano and Micro-Nano.

Comment: Currently I test with micro-nano, changed pins on micro to ICSP and nothing happens. I'm reading about Leonardo/micro and i read that the SS pin works different but I don't know if it's issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the issue, somehow I had to use 10 uF capacitor instead of 4.7 uF

Comment: Where did you have a capacitor?